# Limacon and Polar Graphing

Tags: polar-coordinates

There is a point $P$ in the first quadrant (not including the axes) at which the graph of $r=\cos(4\theta)+\sin(3\theta)$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ intersects itself. Find the angle that the ray from the origin to $P$ makes with the positive $x$-axis.

How would I go about solving this? I believe the point is around (0.8, 0.2), but I don't know the exact point. I also don't know how I would go about finding the angle it makes with the x-axis. Any answers/help would be appreciated.

Comment: The point $P$ is where for two different values $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ we have the same value of $r$, i.e. where the equality $\cos(4\theta_1)+\sin(3\theta_1)= \cos(4\theta_)+\sin(3\theta_2)$. It seems that one solution is $\theta_1=\pi/3$ and $\theta_2=\pi+\pi/3$

Comment: In your answer, is θ that the angle it makes with the x-axis?